# Stop unwanted information from sql columns displaying

Tags: php, mysql

Heloo I would just like to ask if anyone knows of a way of searching the result of a mysql select all and to stop certain information from showing.

I'd like this as the database I am using has some unwanted information I wish not to be shown in the database while also having some information I wish to show so how would I go about censoring the result and stopping certain information from showing.

```
    $query = "SELECT player, data_type, data FROM settings WHERE player = '$searchinfo'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);

echo "<table><tr><th>Username</th>";
echo "<th>Class</th>";
echo "<th>Expirence</th>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die($result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error())) { 
if($result == "title-prefix") {

} else {

 echo '<tr><td>'
 . $row['player'] . '</td><td>'
 . $row['data_type'] . '</td><td>'
 . $row['data'] .  '</td><td> ';

 } }

} }
```

As you can see I tryed to use an if statement to cancel out that certain row but It didn't work.

Comment: the mysql module is deprecated and shouldn't be used, use PDO or mysqli instead. Also use prepared statements.

Comment: what is wanted and what is unwanted ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Echoing the deprecated comments above, but I'll also note that `mysql_query()` returns a resource or `FALSE` for `SELECT` statements, so the comparison `$result == "string"` is never going to be true.

Comment: How would I go about doing it then?

Comment: If you have a column with the "title-prefix" data in it, you need to compare against that row with `if ($row['column'] == "title-prefix") { }`. Again, this is not the best solution. MySQLi with prepared statements will be better.

Also, if the database rows you're trying to hide aren't going to be shown at all, you can leave them out of the returned set with an `AND NOT` or a `!=` in your SQL.

Comment: I don't mean the rows or columns I mean the actual content within. The information it is stored.

Comment: @Connormcwood: Thats what joe is saying... any "content" is stored in a column... you need to test your string against that column.

Comment: oh, I am sorry. I shouldn't of jumped to a conclusion @Joe5150

Answer (score 0):

Store a flag of permissions in the table for each row and modify your guard to test against that.